# Choosing Equal Area Projection for Central Ethiopia (37N)?

Tags: coordinate-system, ethiopia

Can anybody please tell me what is the best equal area projection for central highlands of Ethiopia. I am assuming Albers Equal Area Projection.

Any suggestions?

---

Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area preserves the area of the land therefore minimal distortion in area because of projecting.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend a Map Projection Selection tool.  There is a handy tool called [Projection Wizard](http://projectionwizard.org) (requires much JavaScript), originally from Oregon State University.  With this tool you can specify which distortion property is important for your map and select the specific area of interest.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate projection is Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area Projection with Central Lat. 5 and long. 20.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you recommend this one?

Comment: This should be an edit to the question I think, not an answer